# подключение к socket по https

Tags: javascript, node.js

у меня настроен сайт на https и я настраиваю socket сервер. как мне сделать подключение к нему по https. вот что у меня есть..

server.js

```
var http = require('https').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

на сайте ..

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
<button id="go" name="send">GO</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function () {
var socket = io.connect('https://findquick.it:3000');
$('#go').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents page reloading
  socket.emit('chat message', $('#message').val());
  $('#message').val('');
  return false;
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
  $('.wrapper_messenger').append($('<li>').text(msg));
});
});
 </script>
```

и тут в консоле браузера пишет что Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на [https://findquick.it:3000/socket.io/...(Причина](https://findquick.it:3000/socket.io/...(%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0): не удалось выполнить запрос CORS).[Подробнее]
как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Для этого необходимо, в первую очередь, передать данные SSL сертификата, которые можно получить таким образом:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('path/to/key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('path/to/cert.pem')
};
```

Далее необходимо передать `options` в `.createServer`, сделать это можно так:

```
var http = require('https').createServer(options);
```

Для решения проблемы с CORS можно попробовать использовать `io.origins('*:*')`.

Comment: а где могут находиться .pem файлы на хостинге?

Comment: Вы сможете создать их самостоятельно, взяв информацию о Вашем сертификате и вставив в соответствующий файл.

Comment: т.е. я должен открыть содержание файла сертификата скопировать его и создать текстовый документ вставить и сохранить в формате .pem??

Comment: с сертификатами разобрался но не помогло.
все так же ошибка
Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на https://findquick.it:3000/socket.io/...(Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS).[Подробнее]

Comment: Добавьте в код `io.origins`, как я посоветовал в ответе.

Comment: а в хроме такая ошибка net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Comment: в мозиле заработал чат а в хроме пишет ошибку выше

Comment: Вы используете HTTPS, однако даёте неверные данные SSL сертификата.